# Error with selenium.WebElement.sendKeys()

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am putting together a small app to perform automated checkouts on a Magento site, using Selenium WebDriver in Java. I'm working on learning Java, so I'm adamant on getting this figured out with Java, and not switching to Ruby or Python.

```
package com.huuginn.seleniumMagento;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

/**
 * selenium app for completing checkout in magento
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        //      MagentoCatalog c = new MagentoCatalog();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://plmkt.huuginn.com/");

        WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.id("search"));

        System.out.println(searchField.getClass().getName());
        searchField.clear();
        searchField.sendKeys("sample");
        searchField.submit();
    }
}
```

My getName() line confirms that I am getting the element that I want from the page.

I'm getting this error when compiling:

> [INFO] Compilation failure
>   /seleniumMagento/src/main/java/com/huuginn/seleniumMagento/App.java:[25,13]
>   sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...) in org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
>   cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

sendKeys is expecting a parameter of a type that implements CharSequence (java.lang.String qualifies as such), so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

I am using Java 1.6, and Selenium 2.19, doing my build with Maven.

Comment: What version of WebDriver are you currently using?

Comment: I was using 2.19, but I bumped it to 2.20 in the course of testing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had similar problems with calling `sendKeys()`. The problem usually is, that the signature is a var-ary, that is `CharSequence...` instead of just `CharSequence`.

Of course this should not be a problem with Java 6. My guess would be that your maven compile uses a different compiler setting. Anyways you could change your code to

```
searchField.sendKeys(new String[] { "sample" });
```

to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Needed this for running java in jmeter as well!

Answer (score 1):

I discovered another way to work around this. I was not specifying the version of Java to compile for, so Maven was compiling for an older version. I added this to my pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

That allows me to just a literal string "SAMPLE" in sendKeys() and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating project make sure that you select "Use an execution environment JRE: JavaSE-1.6. You can execute test successfully with out any Sendkeys Error. 100% it will work.