# Java with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, sendkeys, charsequence

I am trying to automate gmail login.

When I enter the text in username input box using `sendKeys()` it is throwing an exception.

My code:

```
WebElement userName =   driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
userName.sendKeys("tutorial");
```

Exception:

```
Error:The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String) at com.gmail.test.Gmaillogin.main(Gmaillogin.java:65)
```

Comment: Based on that snippet, it should work.  A String is a CharSequence so passing in a string literal is absolutely the correct thing to do with that method.  Perhaps providing a bit more of the surrounding code might reveal more?

Edit: Also, what IDE are you using, and what is it's compiler level?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Eclipse helios IDE. Complier compliance level is 1.4 . But , still it is not working.

Comment: Try changing your compiler level to 1.7.  The older java versions have differences in their features which can sometimes product unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

It's tell you that the sendKeys method get only CharSequence[] type.
You have to create CharSequence[] and insert to it your value and use it within sendKeys method.

See this for using CharSequence: [How to convert a String to CharSequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391970/how-to-convert-a-string-to-charsequence)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me out.
I am able to solve above problem.

**Code that worked:**
userName.sendKeys(new String[]{"tutorial"});

For further details please see this link :
[Error when using sendKeys() with Selenium WebDriver Java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694171/error-when-using-sendkeys-with-selenium-web-driver-java-lang-charsequence-cann)

Comment: While this may work, I don't think that this is a good solution.  It's typically bad practice to instantiate a String using new String("").  String literals not working implies that theres some underlying problem, and this solution seems to just subvert it.  Have you tried experimenting with a newer compiler compliance?  I've read before of other people having a similar issue using 1.4 as their compiler level.  But moving up to a newer one fixed it.  Even if you're restricted to 1.4, knowing if it works with 1.6 or 1.7 would help to explain the cause.  That's the one thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Just check and update the Project language level to SDK Default(IntelliJ, not sure about eclipse) under your Project settings, it worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

SendKeys method input should be CharacterSequence array but not String.
But in Java, String is equal to a CharSequence. 
So you can do as following way

```
WebElement userName =   driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
CharacterSequence[] cs = new String[]{"tutorial"};
userName.sendKeys(cs);
```

Comment: When i tried above code :                                                                  WebElement userName =   driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
CharacterSequence[] cs = new String[]{"tutorial"};
userName.sendKeys(cs);                                                                                                       Exception:                                                                                                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Characters Sequence can not be resolved