# Error with sendKeys() function in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver

Following is my code:

```
 WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys(new String[] { "Jacob" });
```

I'm using Selenium 2.44 and Mozilla Firefox 33. Referring the above code, I'm getting a compile time error on `sendKeys()` function and eclipse is asking me to open the "Configure Build Path" window.
The Compiler Compliance Level for eclipse is `1.7`.
Please help me resolving the error with `sendKeys()` function.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9629674/5168011)

Comment: Take a look at this : http://tobeanexpert.blogspot.com/2015/03/resolving-issue-of-type.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is incorrect. Please refer following simplified code,

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.name("firstName"));
           name.sendKeys(new String[] { "Jacob" });
```

**Explanation of your code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys(new String[] { "Jacob" });
```

This returns `void` not `WebElement`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Though both our codes are logically same and correct, your code doesn't seem to work too. It gives me the same error. Could you please suggest a different  solution for the same?

Comment: If you observe carefully our codes are not equals .Above code working in my eclipse .Make sure you have added selenium dependency to maven

Comment: Yes Maven is added and the code which you've suggested doesn't seem to work too.

Answer (score 0):

Match the complier version of Eclipse and Maven. Both should atleast 1.6.
Or refer to below stack:

[Error when using sendKeys() with Selenium WebDriver Java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694171/error-when-using-sendkeys-with-selenium-webdriver-java-lang-charsequence-canno)

Answer (score -3):

You are passing an **array of strings** to sendKeys(), although a simple string would do:

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.name("firstName"));
           name.sendKeys("Jacob");
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The simple way which you have suggested didn't work at first. Hence i went with this method. Could you please suggest a different solution for the same?

Comment: The first answer wasn't from me, that was a different person. What kind of error do you get on this solution? It should be syntactically correct. Maybe you should add an HTML snippet!